# Google Maps API route response different than the original coordinates

Tags: google-maps

I'm working with Google Maps to show a cars last location. Often times this will be in a parking lot off of a main road, however when I input the coordinates for the parking lot `carLatLng` into Google's routing engine the response I get looks to be the nearest road. How do I get it so that the same coordinates I enter are the ones I get from my response?

```
var carLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.9461,-90.07)
var request = {
  origin: carLatLng,
  destination: 
  waypoints: [],
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
};

self.directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

    var lat = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat();
    var lng = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng();

    // lat = 29.946164
    // lng = -90.0702933

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The DirectionsService **always** returns start/end points for driving directions on the road. If you want the result to end somewhere else, you need to extend the polyline yourself (you have the original coordinates, draw a polyline from there to the end of the route from the directions service).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r1swafc/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var carLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.9461, -90.07);
  var carMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: carLatLng
  });
  var request = {
    origin: "Dixon, New Orleans, LA",
    destination: carLatLng,
    waypoints: [],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  };
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true,
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#0000FF"
    }
  })
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      var lat = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lat();
      var lng = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location.lng();
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      map.setCenter(carLatLng);
      map.setZoom(20);
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        path: [carLatLng, response.routes[0].legs[0].end_location]
      });
      // lat = 29.946164
      // lng = -90.0702933

    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up scrapping `directionsService.route` and just using `google.maps.Marker` to update a single point on the map.

Answer (score -1):

I've done a lot lately with Google Map API, unfortunately not with the routing service.

But have a look at these tutorials, they are quite detailed, I found them very helpful at times: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

For your case I'd especially look at part 26 onwards.

Comment: [That tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) is for the (deprecated and turned off) [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info), that version of the API should **not** be used for new code.